# two dimensional arrays , printig the index .?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a working and trying to learn arrays . I got this task .
To print the index of the array witch is made of full 1 .
I have bad English so let me try to explain with examples .

```
int main()
{
  int n,m,i,j,suma1,suma2;
  int a[4][3]={
  {1,1,1},
  {1,0,0},
  {1,1,1},
  {1,1,1}};
```

First of all we are making a following array . So what actually i need to print is the index like this

```
0,0
2,0
3,0
```

So what i am printing are the array fields who are filled up with 1 till the end . 
I had the following code .

```
n=4,m=3,suma1=0,suma2=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      {
        if(a[i][j]==1)
        suma1+=1;
      }
      if(suma1==m-1)
      {
          for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          {
              if(a[i][j]==1)
              suma2+=1;
          }
          if(suma2==n-1)
          printf("%d%d",i,j);
      }
      suma1=0;
      suma2=0;
  }
}
```

But i don't get any output .. Can someone tell me where my mistake is ?

Comment: Doing `for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      {
        suma1+=1;
      }` is equal to just `suma1 = m`.

Comment: There's no need to recalculate `suma1` each time. It's just the number of columns, it's the same for each row.

Comment: damn you are right i fixed but still not working , i will edit the code in a minute

Comment: i edited the code but , still not working , as i expected .

Comment: maybe try adding a `\n` to your output so that the output is flushed

Comment: not working @ChrisTurner

Comment: also your logic doesn't make sense - surely a full row would be when `suma1 == m`?

Comment: @ChrisTurner fixed that and still not working , code edited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i unterstand what you want to do. but if you want to print all "coordinates" of value 1.

this should do the job

--old 1

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                        

int main()                                                                                                
{                                                                                                         
    int n,m,i,j,suma1,suma2;                                                                              
    int a[4][3]={                                                                                         
        {1,1,1},                                                                                          
        {1,0,0},                                                                                          
        {1,1,1},                                                                                          
        {1,1,1}};                                                                                         

    for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++)                                                                          
        {                                                                                                 
            for (int j = 0; j != 3; j++)                                                                  
                if (a[i][j] == 1)                                                                         
                    printf("%d,%d\n", i, j);                                                              
        }                                                                                                 
    return (0);                                                                                           
}
```

--old 2

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                        

int main()                                                                                                
{                                                                                                         
    int cnt_line;                                                                                         
    int a[4][3]={                                                                                         
        {1,1,1},                                                                                          
        {1,0,0},                                                                                          
        {1,1,1},                                                                                          
        {1,1,1}};                                                                                         

    for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++)                                                                          
        {                                                                                                 
            cnt_line = 0;                                                                                 
            for (int j = 0; j != 3; j++)                                                                  
                if (a[i][j] == 1)                                                                         
                    cnt_line++;                                                                           
            if (cnt_line == 3)                                                                            
                printf("%d,0\n", i);                                                                      
        }                                                                                                 
    return (0);                                                                                           
}
```

-- New

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int cnt_line;
    int cnt_cols;
    int a[4][3] = {
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}
    };

    for (int i = 0; i != 4; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j != 3; j++)
            if (a[i][j] == 1) {
                cnt_cols = 0;
                cnt_line = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k != 4; k++)
                    if (a[k][j] == 1)
                        cnt_line++;
                if (cnt_line == 4) {
                    for (int l = 0; l != 3; l++)
                        if (a[i][l] == 1)
                            cnt_cols++;
                    if (cnt_cols == 3)
                        printf("%d,%d\n", i, j);
                }
            }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: this is fine but i need to print only if the row and the colume have 1 till the end .

Comment: first you check if the collom is full of 1 then the row and if the row and collom is full of 1 then you print the index of them

Comment: How ok! give me one minute

Comment: this is what you want ??